# Jenkins : Clean workspaces with Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have Jenkins setup without nodes, all builds are run on the same machine.
I want to setup a Groovy script to cleanup old workspaces, so I want to use:

```
proj.scm.processWorkspaceBeforeDeletion(@Nonnull Job<?,?> project,
                                        @Nonnull FilePath workspace,
                                        @Nonnull Node node)
```

What value should I put for `node` when on master?

Comment: Hint: There's the [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) if it's not about old workspaces but about current.

Comment: In fact I want to keep workspaces available for users to be able to investigate, I only empty workspaces when they are older than a month, meaning no real activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute below script to clean-up all Jenkins workspaces with `Groovy`:

```
import hudson.model.* // For each project

for(item in Jenkins.instance.items)      
{ // check that job is not building
    if(!item.isBuilding())     
    { 
         println("Wiping out workspace of job "+item.name)    
         item.doDoWipeOutWorkspace() 
    } else { 
         println("Skipping job "+item.name+", currently building") 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `Jenkins.instance`, since [`Hudson.getInstance()`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Hudson.html#getInstance%28%29) is deprecated?

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.doDoWipeOutWorkspace()

Comment: This solution does not work anymore. `isBuilding()` isn't supported. `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder.isBuilding() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: isBuildable(), isBuildable()`